# Замена iframes на Tables

Tags: html, iframe

Подскажите как заменить фреймы на div или table.

Нужно переписать такой код:

```
<FRAMESET ROWS="50%,*, 60,0,0,0" FRAMEBORDER=0 FRAMESPACING=0 BORDERCOLOR=#000000>
   <FRAME SRC="game.php?fun=m_location&map=1" NAME="_location" SCROLLING="AUTO" FRAMEBORDER=0>
   <frameset cols="*,250" FRAMEBORDER=0 FRAMESPACING=0 BORDERCOLOR=#000000>
     <FRAME SRC="game/m_chat.php" NAME="_chat" SCROLLING="YES" FRAMEBORDER=0>
     <FRAME SRC="game.php?fun=m_online&map=1" NAME="_online" SCROLLING="YES" FRAMEBORDER=0>
   </FRAMESET>
   <FRAME SRC="game.php?fun=m_input&map=1" NAME="_input" SCROLLING="NO" FRAMEBORDER=0 NORESIZE>
   <FRAME SRC="" NAME="_work" NORESIZE>
   <FRAME SRC="" NAME="_chat_work" NORESIZE>
   <FRAME SRC="" NAME="_chat_add" NORESIZE>
</FRAMESET>
```

На div или table

Пробовал так:

```
<table border=0>
<tr style="width:100%;height:50%;"><td name="location" border=0>text</td></tr>
<tr style="height:35%;">
<td name="chat" border=0 style="width:70%;">text</td>
<td name="UsersOnline" border=0 style="width:30%;">text</td>
</tr>
<tr><td name="input" border=0>text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Не получилось =(

Comment: Мне ответять?

Comment: @Riolu, врятли... Вопрос очень глупый и ответ на него можно найти в поисковике. А еще то, как вы пытались заменить iframe на table это просто жуть. Как вы додумались до такого. И еще желательно не требовать ответа...Будьте спокойны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@KryDos](/users/10495/krydos) все таки я отвечу, все мы такими по началу были, используйте уже существующие макеты сайтов http://htmlbook.ru/layout а дальше прикуривайте свои велосипеды

Comment: Спс но я уже сам придумал =)